# Bootstrap 3 button always bottom right in tab?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Is it possible to have button always at bottom right in bootstrap 3 tab?

Here is example of my code in tabs

```
<div class="wizard tab-content">
    <!--Step 1 --> 
    <div id="step-1" class="tab-pane fade in active">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <h2>First step</h2>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                <a href="#step-1" data-toggle="tab">BACK</a> 
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 text-right">
                <a href="#step-2" data-toggle="tab">NEXT</a> 
            </div>
        </div>        
    </div>
    <!--/Step 1 --> 
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wizard{
     min-height:400px;
     background-color:red;
}
```

What i need is that BACk and NEXT to be always at bottom of wizard element?

Please take a look at this working fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/9126/

Comment: try: http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/9127/

Comment: you solution is the best, because i dont need much media queriees, can you make answer that i can accept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See: try: http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/9127

In fact this solution does not differ much from that by @Izzy:

CSS:

```
.wizard {
 min-height:200px;
 background-color:red;
 position: relative;
}
.wizard .tab-pane > div:last-child {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  margin:0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Firstly add `position:relative` to `.wizard` div and then you can use `position:absolute` for the **BACK** and **NEXT**. So something like

```
.wizard {
min-height:400px;
background-color:red;
position: relative;
}

.col-md-6 {
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
}
```